# C++ MVC - data validation

Tags: c++, qt, validation, user-interface, model-view-controller

**Short form:** Do I violate MVC if I validate data input by the user (through the View) in the Controller? Does it really have to be done in the Model (I read that someplace)?

**Long form:**
Suppose I have a C++ Model-View-Controller forum application (whose GUI is made using Qt, if it matters). I have a View and its Controller. A user is authenticated and presses the "New Post" button. The only thing the button's action listener does is that it calls Controller->createNewPost() and this latter method does this:

string postContent = View->readPostContentFromInputDialog(); (this method displays a dialog to the user containing a text box and returns what was typed as a string)

Now, what's left to do is:

1. validate that the postContent has at least 3 characters
2. store the post in some kind of database (the current user's username/id is known and will be associated with the postContent when stored to the database)

The problem is the following: it would be relatively easy to do this check right here in the Controller. However, I understand that data validation in MVC (I'm constrained to use MVC) should be done in the Model.

So, let's suppose I call Model->store(postContent), which also does validation for the data to decide if it's going to be stored or not. But in case of invalid data, what would be the best way to return *what was wrong* to the Controller so that it can display an error through the View (if(INVALID DATA) View->displayErrorDialog("WHAT WAS WRONG");)? I could just make the Model->store method return true/false, but the REAL problem is how do I return detalis about WHAT was invalid? I guess exceptions could work here, but it seems quite complicated to do this every time I have to validate user input (not just for the "New Post" action).

It seems easier to just check in the Controller, so does this REALLY violate MVC? Or, could you please suggest me some other way of returning (from Model to Controller) what was invalid regarding the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although MVC pattern is well-defined in terms of interface/logic separation, in your projects you can construe that definition to what-ever extent you wish. Keep in mind, however, that this might come at the price, and straying from precise implementation might cause some complications in future, when you decide to build some additional functionality on your existing code. 
Now, if you want to go for the clean implementation, you Have to put any kind of "processing" into your Model. Moreover, you Do Not return anything from the Model to the Controller. 
If you have a View which presents a user with a text box perhaps, which has to be validated, then the normal course of action would be for view to urge the user to input whatever it is that you expect, pass it to the Controller which might implement event listeners for View, then, from Controller you should pass the information obtained to Model. Model in turn, might implement Observer pattern, and be a subject of observation for View and notify it with the result of its internal processing, or just give a little nudge for View to know that it's time for updating its containers.
So, to summarise:
You might want to implement Observer pattern and make Model observable by View. When View is changed, pass the information to Controller, which might be done implicitly by event listeners, and then give that information to Model. Upon receiving it Model should invoke an `notify();` to let all observers know that it has been updated, and then, in View, implement a function `update();` which, when has been notified, will upload the information from Model and display it accordingly. 
In your case, you might even want to consider overloading `update();` as `update(bool passedValidation);`. That way, if model decides that input was invalid, you would not even have to make a call to Model and instead display the error message right away.

Comment: Thank you for your help :).